# Python list : IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am currently learning. I got text file with variable number of spaces in between words per line:
I am trying to read it as follows:

```
        import re
   ...: results = []
   ...: with open ("../../103.Immune_gene_families/Immune_genes/Human/human_immunegene.hits") as file:
   ...:     for line in file:
   ...:         if not line.startswith("#"):
   ...:             line = re.sub("\s\s+" , " ", line)
   ...:             #print(line)
   ...:             ens_id = line.split(" ")[1]
   ...:             print(ens_id)
   ...:
```

But I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-469f5598d359> in <module>
      6             line = re.sub("\s\s+" , " ", line)
      7             #print(line)
----> 8             ens_id = line.split(" ")[1]
      9             print(ens_id)
     10

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Example lines I get with

```
print(line)
['ENSG00000128016', '115', '138', '107', '147', 'TF106503', '9', '32', '5.9', '8.3', '0', 'No_clan', '']
['ENSG00000128016', '135', '169', '130', '172', 'TF317698', '454', '488', '18.0', '0.00073', '0', 'No_clan', '']
['ENSG00000128016', '137', '175', '134', '196', 'TF318914', '95', '132', '21.9', '8e-05', '0', 'No_clan', '']
['ENSG00000128016', '137', '167', '130', '173', 'TF326635', '1096', '1127', '5.7', '3.3', '0', 'No_clan', '']
['ENSG00000128016', '138', '170', '133', '173', 'TF329017', '881', '912', '5.3', '4.3', '0', 'No_clan', '']
['ENSG00000128016', '139', '166', '129', '173', 'TF105541', '764', '791', '9.3', '0.38', '0', 'No_clan', '']
['ENSG00000128016', '139', '166', '132', '172', 'TF105970', '278', '305', '8.4', '0.6', '0', 'No_clan', '']
['ENSG00000128016', '140', '170', '131', '174', 'TF314946', '110', '140', '4.5', '6.3', '0', 'No_clan', '']
['ENSG00000128016', '142', '167', '134', '184', 'TF329287', '9', '33', '6.8', '2.3', '0', 'No_clan', '']
```

If you could help me on this regard, much appreciated.

Thank you,
AK

Comment: That probably happens on an *empty* line…!?

Comment: List indices in Python are starting at 0. It seems as some of your created lists do only contain 1 or zero elements. So you get an error as you try to access the second element in the list with line.split(" ")[1].

Comment: `line` is already a list. Why do you want to split it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

If you run

```
string = 'abc'
print(string.split(' '))
```

you will see that the result is

```
['abc']
```

If you tried to `string.split(' ')[1]`, you would generate an `IndexError`.

So what is happening is that, somewhere, you likely don't have the character that you are splitting on.

Comment: Hi @slightlynybbledThank you for the reply. Would you please show me how to remove if there is any empty lines from the text file.

Comment: Hi, I first removed the empty lines from the text with sed '/^$/d' -i text.file and re-run the code. It worked. It would have been great if I could do it with in python itself.

Comment: Within your `for` loop: `if not line.strip() == '': process_line()`

Answer (score 0):

You get the index error because there is less than 2 elements in `line.split(" ")`,
also meaning there was less than 2 spaces in `line`. Try `line.split(" ")[0]` instead:

```
import re
results = []
with open ("../../103.Immune_gene_families/Immune_genes/Human/human_immunegene.hits") as file:
    for line in file:
        if not line.startswith("#"):
            line = re.sub("\s\s+" , " ", line)
            #print(line)
            ens_id = line.split(" ")[0]
            print(ens_id)
```

Comment: Thank you! It is apparently due to empty lines in the text.